# Can't access formik.touched && formik.errors with Yup of internal property of an object

Tags: formik, yup, react-typescript, nested-object

First timer...

I am using formik with yup form validation in react typescript and trying to get formik.touched && formik.errors for nested object .

whatever I tried not working

how should I get to the nested object ?

`{formik.touched.address?.state && formik.errors.address?.state && ( <p className="text-danger">{formik.errors.address?.state}</p> )}`

```
 validationSchema: yup.object({
      firstName: yup.string().required().min(2),
      lastName: yup.string().required().min(2),
      email: yup.string().required().email(),
      address: yup.object({
        country: yup.string().required().min(2),
        state: yup.string().min(2),      }),
     }),

return 
          <div className="form-floating col-6 mb-3 mt-3">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="floatingState"
              placeholder="John Doe"
              name="state"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.address?.state}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            ></input>
            <label`your text` htmlFor="floatingState">State</label>
            {formik.touched.address?.state && formik.errors.address?.state && (
              <p className="text-danger">{formik.errors.address?.state}</p>
            )}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set `initialValues` for address if you haven't

```
 initialValues={
        // other fields...
        address: {
          country: ''
          state: ''
        }
      }
```

And change value of `name` attribute of input to `name="address.state"`, since `state` is inside *address* object.

Comment: Thank you Usama!

I have had the initial values already an was able the get to address.state.
my problem is that I am getting errors on the formik.touched and formik.errors when I try to check the address.state ...

{formik.touched.address?.state && formik.errors.address?.state && ( <p className="text-danger">{formik.errors.address?.state}</p> )}

Answer (score 0):

Input name should also be nested.

```
name="address.state"
```